# Improve fetch request load speed

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, fetch

I have a web scraper that that basically fetches the html page and scrapes text data using [cheerio.js](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio)

It takes about ~2sec to retrieve the data but I'm looking for way to improve this. The biggest bottleneck is fetching the html  which takes about 1.0-1.7sec to load on average. Are they any techniques that I could use to improve this? For instance there are auto-play videos and images that I don't need is there a way to block those elements?

Things I've tried:
I have changed the user-agent to a mobile device so I can retrieve the mobile version of the website but it hasn't much of a difference.

P.S the scraper is hosted on Heroku free tier.

The code I'm trying to improve

```
const USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/56.0.2924.75 Mobile/14E5239e Safari/602.1'

function getHTML(url) {
    return axios.get(url,
        {
            timeout: 5000,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'text/html',
                'user-agent': `${USER_AGENT}`
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            return response.data
        })
        .catch(error => { console.log(error); return null })
 }
```

The above code return the html which than I scrape with cheerio in the functions below.

```
 async function getData(url)  { 
        ... 
    
        await getHTML(url).then((html) => {
                const $ = cheerio.load(html)
                if ($(html).find('#quote-header-info')) {
                    const info = $('info-box').text()
                }
    
                //More scraping 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please make this a [mcve]

Comment: Neither cheerio nor axios load any external resources like videos, images, scripts, or stylesheets. If your html file loads too slow, it's either huge, your connection is very slow, or it's the fault of the server.

Comment: I added some code to the original question